# Can't run the "rDEA" package, in R

Tags: r

I'm terrible when it comes to run models with R. I'm trying to run the following command, that can be found [here](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiSrqTExeLRAhXCEpAKHcctAg8QFggjMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2FrDEA%2FrDEA.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF2lo7-4z2JbfLAezR5sDuxu5lUZg&sig2=8khhbhNzAFsIl5M_uYtftg):

```
## load data on Japanese hospitals (Besstremyannaya 2013, 2011)
data("hospitals", package="rDEA")
## inputs and outputs for analysis
Y = hospitals[c('inpatients', 'outpatients')]
X = hospitals[c('labor', 'capital')]
W = hospitals[c('labor_price', 'capital_price')]
## Naive input-oriented DEA score for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
firms=1:20
di_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], model="input", RTS="variable")
di_naive$thetaOpt
## Naive DEA score in cost-minimization model for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
ci_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], W=W[firms,],
model="costmin", RTS="variable")
ci_naive$XOpt
ci_naive$gammaOpt
```

The command works very well, but, when I try to run the command applied to my data, I get the this stuff here:

```
> ## inputs and outputs for analysis
> Y = data[c('V7', 'V8')]
Error in data[c("V7", "V8")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> X = data[c('V3', 'V4','V5','V6')]
Error in data[c("V3", "V4", "V5", "V6")] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> W = data[c('V2')]
Error in data[c("V2")] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
> ## Naive input-oriented DEA score for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
> firms=1:19
> di_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], model="input", RTS="variable")
Error in dea.input(XREF = XREF, YREF = YREF, X = X, Y = Y, RTS = RTS) : 
  object 'X' not found
> di_naive$thetaOpt
Error: object 'di_naive' not found
> ## Naive DEA score in cost-minimization model for the first 20 firms under variable returns-to-scale
> ci_naive = dea(XREF=X, YREF=Y, X=X[firms,], Y=Y[firms,], W=W[firms,],
+                model="costmin", RTS="variable")
Error in dea.costmin(XREF = XREF, YREF = YREF, X = X, Y = Y, W = W, RTS = RTS) : 
  object 'X' not found
> ci_naive$XOpt
Error: object 'ci_naive' not found
> ci_naive$gammaOpt
Error: object 'ci_naive' not found
>
```

Someone can give me a hand?

Comment: Could you post an example and structure of your data?

Comment: `data` is an R function name. You do not appear to have a data-object named `data` in your workspace and so R is telling you that you cannot extract a column from a function. Your data -object might be spelled differently than you think or ... guessing you are an immigrant from SAS and you did `read.table` and didn't assign the result to a name. Voting to close as not reproducible. ( doubt that the error has anything to do with the rDEA package.)

Comment: Are you missing comma here: ´Y = hospitals[c('inpatients', 'outpatients')]´, should be  ´Y = hospitals[,c('inpatients', 'outpatients')]´?